# SCA Tools not available?

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins, components, sca

I am trying to download an eclipse plugin that helps in designing Service Component Architecture (SCA) system. I specifically need a tool that allows me to create an SCA component diagram, and that diagram can be also exported as XML.

Every time I search for that, I find a plugin called "SCA Tools". However, the weird thing is that the download link keeps directing me to a page with the following message:

```
404 File not found
We're sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.
```

Here's the page which contains the download link: http://www.eclipse.org/soa/sca/
and here's the download page of the plugin: http://www.eclipse.org/project/download.php

I tried another way by searching in eclipse itself for the plugin, but I ended up with the same result.

What's going on with this tool? If it is not available, what other alternatives that I can go with? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse web site seems to have been reworked a lot lately and seems to be a bit of a mess for some projects!

You can install the SCA Tools using `Help > Install New Software`. Choose your main Eclipse install repository to work with (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler for Eclipse Kepler). SCA Tools should be under the SOA Development section.

Comment: The SCA tool is amazing. Thank you!